# how to return different actions in struts2

Tags: struts2, action

I am coding login module, based on the role I want to return different action. I am having code for the different actions in my struts.xml:

```
if (role == 1) {
   Sysyem.out.println("I am a admin");
   return "adminaction";
} else if (role == 2) {
   Sysyem.out.println("I am a Manager");
   return "adminaction";
} else if (role == 3) {
   Sysyem.out.println("I am a BA");
   return "adminaction";
}
```

Is there any other way to handle this struts 2. In struts 1 we used to do it by actionforward. We assign some value to action forward and finally return it.

Answer (score 1):

**youractionClass**

```
if (role == 1) {
   Sysyem.out.println("I am a admin");
   return "admin";
} else if (role == 2) {
   Sysyem.out.println("I am a Manager");
   return "manager";
} else if (role == 3) {
   Sysyem.out.println("I am a BA");
   return "ba";
}
```

Now inside **struts.xml** simply mention the string in the `name` attribute of `result` as follows

```
<action name="loginAction" class="youractionClass">  
   <result name="admin" type="redirect">adminaction</result>
   <result name="manager" type="redirect">managerAction</result>
   <result name="ba" type="redirect">baAction</result>
</action>
```

Comment: If you have x admin actions, y manager actions, and z baActions, then creating a package for each and an appropriate interceptor which checks the session for the appropriate rights (So a user could be granted BA and Manager rights but not admin) would be easy, flexible and not produce spaghetti actions like the above strategy will... (This isn't to critique what you provided anu, you answered exactly what was asked... I'm just saying to the OP this strategy has issues and for all but the trivial case shouldn't be used).